# CXF InFaultInterceptor vs. OutFaultInterceptor

Tags: java, cxf, interceptor, cxfrs

I am working on REST API with CXF framework. Anybody can explain to me more detail about what's different between InFaultInterceptor vs. OutFaultInterceptor? They seems belong to different phase of interceptor. But Do we should put what logic into different Fault Interceptor? I need to abort interceptor chain and response custom response message. I cannot see different on InFaultInterceptor and OutFaultInterceptor for my scenario. What's your typical error handler interceptor? Could you brief introduce your error handling structure of CXF if convenient?

Answer (score 0):

The concept in the interceptor chain is pretty straightforward, in is coming in, out is going out.

For instance, if you want to change the way faults are populated in a SOAP Fault, say to get some variable you are putting in the exception you are throwing, you would use say the Soap12FaultOutInterceptor to modify the fault you are generating. The Soap12FaultInInterceptor would be used to handle incoming faults.

My real question is why do you want to use the interceptor chain, and what is your use case? This is not unusual, but many times unnecessary especially with Spring and aspecting, IMO.